# Webpack more than triples original module size

Tags: typescript, firebase, webpack, bundle

I have my environment set up where I write client-side JS code in TypeScript (to gain the benefits of using TS) and use Webpack to bundle it into my public directory in my Firebase project. I've found that Webpack seems to be adding quite a lot of overhead to my code. Packing up a file that merely only imports the Firestore module ends up with about 300 KiB of code when the original file is <100KiB.

Here is a minimal configuration that still has the same behavior:

`index.ts`

```
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

`webpack.config.ts`

```
import { Configuration } from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';

const config: Configuration = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.ts'),
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[chunkhash].js'
      },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.ts', '.js' ],
        modules: ['node_modules'],
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
    },
}

export default config;
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "outDir": "lib",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "strict": true,
        "target": "es2017",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
    },
    "compileOnSave": true,
}
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "webpack-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^8.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.11",
    "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.5",
    "webpack": "^5.4.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
  }
}
```

As explained above, the final bundle size is 300+ KiB, when the file that's being imported is <100 KiB. What can I do so that my bundle isn't tripling in size?

Comment: You should delete your original post.  It's going to cause problems if you leave it up.

Comment: Are you counting the size of the dependencies?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I deleted my original post. As for counting the size of the dependencies, all I am doing is running webpack on that one entry file, `index.ts`. And all that file does is import the firestore module. Webpack outputs a `main.js` file which is over 300KiB. The original firestore module is under 100KiB. I'm confused as to how Webpack is more than tripling the original code size.

Comment: Webpack adds a lot of its own scaffolding to the build.  You should manually strip that out to see what's left.  But you will need to leave it in so it can do its work when you run the app.

Comment: @DougStevenson if this is just how Webpack does things, then I don't really know why people would ever use it in this context because it just negates the performance gains of the small original code. I saw a YouTube video earlier in which a Google engineer said they were able to get a <200KiB vendors bundle for a project, and I'm honestly not sure how they did it.

Comment: Most people don't just include one module.  They include dozens, and they want to load them dynamically.  You  will have a hard time implementing that without a bundler to manage all those details.

Comment: @DougStevenson but the scaffolding is going to be there, nonetheless, right? So even if I import 20 more modules, that firestore code is still going to take up about 300KiB of my bundle, it seems. It was still that large when I was importing a few others along with it.

Comment: Do whatever you see fit for your application.  There are a lot of ways you can put it together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this looks like it's a known issue. It was first mention in [this issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2241) in the Firebase JS SDK GitHub (with conversation moving [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/332)). It looks like there's a pretty involved workaround [here](https://davidea.st/articles/firebase-bundle-size), or I could just use the experimental version of the Firebase JS SDK.